# filtrar entre duas datas com join

Tags: sql, join, where

Tenho duas tabelas: `col` (colaborador) e `Indicacao`.

Fiz um `select` para saber quantas indicações tem cada colaborador. Está funcionando mas não consigo filtrar por data usando `between`.

```
SELECT c.id, c.nome, funcao, area, count(p.cpf_cli) AS quantidade FROM 
col c LEFT JOIN
indicacao p ON p.id_colaborador = c.id GROUP BY c.id, c.nome ORDER BY
c.nome
```

Tentei com `between` mas não funcionou.

```
SELECT c.id, c.nome, funcao, area, count(p.cpf_cli) AS quantidade FROM 
col c LEFT JOIN
indicacao p ON p.id_colaborador = c.id GROUP BY c.id, c.nome ORDER BY
c.nome WHERE indicacao.data_ind BETWEEN `2018/09/20` AND '2018/09/21'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lembre-se sempre que palavras reservadas como `GROUP BY` e `ORDER BY` vem depois do `WHERE`.

Outra coisa é que toda coluna que não está sendo utilizada em funções de agrupamento com `SUM`, `COUNT`, `AVG` etc, precisam ser listadas na cláusula `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT 
   c.id, 
   c.nome, 
   funcao, 
   area, 
   count(p.cpf_cli) AS quantidade 
FROM col c 
LEFT JOIN indicacao p 
   ON p.id_colaborador = c.id 
WHERE 
   indicacao.data_ind BETWEEN `2018/09/20` AND '2018/09/21'
GROUP BY 
   c.id, c.nome 
ORDER BY
   c.nome
```

Comment: deu certo aqui cara, muito obrigado